# Como puedo inhabilitar un input cuando tengo un valor de un select en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

en mi html tengo declarado un input y un select... al seleccionar en el select el cual tiene un arreglo que contiene los valores de "2020" "2021" y "no aplica" ... al seleccionar no aplica este debe bloquear el input que muestro a continuacion....

```
html  


 <mat-select formControlName="anio"class="select-declaracion-islr" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Año" (change)="fechaNull($event)"
                matTooltip= "Si la empresa esta constituida recientemente, seleccionar la opcion No aplica" matTooltipPosition='below' >
                <mat-option  *ngFor="let anio of fecha anio" [value]="anio">{{anio}}</mat-option >
              </mat-select>
              <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('anio')?.hasError('required')">Campo Requerido*</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class=" col xl4 l4 m4 s4">
            <mat-form-field>
              <br>
                               
              <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" matInput currencyMask 
                        [options]="{ allowNegative: false, prefix: '', thousands: '.', 
                       decimal: ',' }"
                        placeholder="Monto" 
                        maxlength="20" formControlName="monto" required/> 
                        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('monto')?.hasError('required')">Campo 
            Requerido*</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

js

esta es la funcion que recorre mi arreglo , la cual me muestra el año anterior, el año actual y no aplica....

```
 public fechasIsrl(){


const anoActual = moment().year();
const anoPasado = moment().year() -1 ;
const sinFecha = "NO APLICA"

this.fecha.push(anoActual, anoPasado, sinFecha,)

}
```

funcion donde voy a declarar con que valor el input debe bloquearse y cuando no

```
 public fechaNull(fechasIsrl){
 if(const sinFecha =="NO APLICA"){
 this.fechasIsrl.GET("monto").enabled(false);
 }else{
 this.fechasIsrl.GET("monto").enabled(true);
  }
 } 
}
```

creo que le estoy pasando los datos de entrada mal al js para que realice la acción... cualquier información que pueda aportar para resolver la problemática estoy a la orden

Answer (score 0):

usa el evento (selectionChange)="funcion()":

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="cambio()">

</mat-select>

<input [disabled]="input-state">
```

y en el ts del componente abstrae el valor del select para compara

```
input-state: boolean = true;
sinFecha = "NO APLICA";
public cambio(){
     if(this.form.get('anio') === this.sinFecha){
          this.input-state= false;
     }
}
```

Saludos.